# Problems with Goland's Debugger

Tags: pointers, debugging, go, struct, goland

I have got a strange bug in Golang.

> OS: Linux Ubuntu 18.04.
>
> CPU: AMD with 64 Bit Support.
>
> IDE is Goland 2018.1.5.
>
> Go version is 1.10.1.
>
> Compiler is set to: 'Any'.

I have tried both 'gc' and 'gccgo' compilers. Result is the same.

In the program below, Debugger shows strange things. The 'aUnion' variable has "John" inside it, but the 'aRecord' variable which has a Union type in it, has no "John" inside.

If i 'fmt.Printf' them, they are both there, but Debugger shows no John inside 'aRecord'.
Is that a debugger's bug?

The program is very simple. Just nested structs passed as a pointer.

```
    // 33.go.

    package main

    import "fmt"

    type Person struct {
        Name string
        Age  int
    }
    type GroupOfPeople struct {
        Name   string
        People []*Person
    }
    type Union struct {
        ID    int
        Group *GroupOfPeople
    }
    type Record struct {
        UnionField *Union
        Type       int
    }

    func main() {

        var aPerson *Person
        var people []*Person
        var aGroup *GroupOfPeople
        var aUnion *Union
        var aRecord *Record

        aPerson = &Person{
            Name: "John",
            Age:  10,
        }
        people = []*Person{aPerson}
        aGroup = &GroupOfPeople{
            Name:   "A Group",
            People: people,
        }
        aUnion = &Union{
            ID:    123,
            Group: aGroup,
        } // John is inside 'aUnion'.
        aRecord = &Record{
            UnionField: aUnion,
            Type:       666,
        }
        // John is NOT inside 'aRecord'.
        // WHY ?!
        fmt.Printf("aUnion: %+v.\r\n", aUnion.Group.People[0])
        fmt.Printf("aRecord: %+v.\r\n", aRecord.UnionField.Group.People[0])
    }
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: I just tried it and both output lines have "John" in them. What happens if you compile and run this program from the command line (`go run file.go`)?

Comment: I have edited the question. fmt.Printf shows John in both structs. The main problem is that built-in Goland's Debugger does not show John inside 'aRecord'. I wonder why is that and how to fix it.

Comment: try to inspect them in debugger. you will be surprised...

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Here is an MCVE which produces the expected result: https://play.golang.org/p/O_TkFDcunUU Please provide precise, detailed instructions on how to reproduce your issue.

Comment: 'play.golang.org' has no debugger on their website. To reproduce the problem you can debug the code in Goland program of the specified version. Set a breakpoint on a last line of the code and inspect two variables which i mentioned. Do you understand what i tell you?

Comment: Here is the evidence of a strange behaviour of the debugger. 2 Images. Feel the difference. 1. https://imghost.io/image/fGdA8 2. https://imghost.io/image/fGcjX Do you understand now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem in how GoLand handles the nesting for the values of these variables at runtime.

I created [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-5880) to track and fix it.

Meanwhile, you can use the "Watches" functionality to watch for "aRecord.UnionField.Group.People" as an example, which will then correctly display the values. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: And a small update. This will be fixed in 2018.2 release, and if you want to try it earlier, you can use the next EAP release after 2018.2 EAP 3.